# Расширение для Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Подскажите, каким образом добавить свой пункт меню к меню DevTools?

Суть в следующем, при инспектировании кода, при клике правой кнопкой мыши появляется контекстное меню

[image: меню DevTools]
Хотелось бы добавить в него свой пункт, и отловить событие клика по нему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из консоли можно обращаться к выделенному элементу через `$0`. Соответственно, если ты добавишь нужную функцию на страницу, то сможешь передать ей элемент руками из консоли.

Comment: Уже интересней... А можно более подробный пример того что надо написать в консоли? И сразу вопрос, а можно ли программно писать в консоли команды?

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, ну, предположим, ты добавил на страницу метод `doSomeMagic` - вызываешь его из консоли как `doSomeMagic($0)` и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего **никак**, в оф. доках нигде не указана возможность работы с контекстным меню вызванным из `devTools` хрома.
Весь интерфейс для расширения ограничивается только:

- `inspectedWindow`
- `network`
- `panels`

`Panels`, как сначала может показаться, доступа к контекстному меню не предоставляет.

`network` - работа с сетью.

`inspectwindow` - доступ к текущему окну, в котором открыт `devTools`.

[Почитать, поразбираться](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools)

**UPD**:
Я вот что подумал, последний выделенный элемент в консоли доступен по ссылке `$0`, может быть попробовать воспользоваться ею? Что бы получить код, можете сделать так `$0.outerHtml`

Comment: На самом деле хотелось бы реализовать следующее. Получить блок кода который выделен в инспекторе, на скрине выделен синей полосой на котором произведен клик правой кнопкой мыши, и отправить его на определенный урл запросом post для обработки сторонним приложением. Идеально было бы через меню, но если нет возможности, может подскажете как добыть выделенный код, желательно исходный а не Dom иерархию.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, в одном своем расширении я использовал обычное контекстное меню, в которое Chrome Extensions уже позволяют добавить свой пункт. Достаточно просто повесить обработчик на клик и записать элемент из события в переменную, а далее обработать переменную после выбора пункта контекстного меню. Если это подходит, то могу описать чуть подробнее в отдельном ответе. Правда я не очень понимаю ваш комментарий про "исходный код, а не Dom иерархию".

Comment: Дело в том что мы не видим явного выделения элементов при таком клике, а при перемещении курсора в инспекторе кода над элементами, мы видим как они подсвечиваются, далее выделяем его и можем например скопировать код этого элемента со всей его иерархией, или получить XPath выражение доступа к этому элементу. По поводу исходного кода и Dom они же не равны, один в тексте а другой вложенными объектами, так вот надо получить именно кусок исходного HTML кода, который можно было бы операцией замены строк, заменить в исходной странице.